# Git log to show ALL the commit messages of the merged branch

Tags: git

I have a feature branch and a master branch where the feature branch has been merged into.
I need to get the list of all commits that took place in the feature branch. To do so I do (master is checked out):

```
git log --since="2022-09-09T00:00+12:00" --until="2022-09-10T00:00+12:00" --date=iso-strict  --pretty=format:"%x7c%H%x7c%B%ad%x7c" --graph
```

What I get is

```
Merge in CON/ih-webserver from feature/IH-6452-add-parapet-backside-palette-part to master 
 
* commit '0db13700603e2faa0f0ec568d9677b5e16ddfb1f': (58 commits) 
  IH-6452 format 
  IH-6452 format 
  IH-6452 fix create room_type_surface based on franchise_type 
  IH-6452 rolling back changes 
  IH-6452 create room_type_surface based on franchise_type 
  IH-6452 fix room_type_surface query 
  IH-6452 fix column name 
  IH-6452 remove unrequired Min function 
  IH-6452 remove unrequired Min function 
  IH-6452 format 
  IH-6452 remove unused kitset 
  IH-6452 take bom_category and bom_sub_category id from query 
  IH-6452 use existing part 
  IH-6452 update supply_unit query 
  IH-6452 add temp part name identifier 
  IH-6452 add comments 
  IH-6452 fixing uref in insert part query 
  IH-6452 revert test case wrong value 
  IH-6452 add filtering by part uref 
  IH-6452 add pending bug ticket todo comments 
  ...
```

As you can see the list contains 20 latest commits only, however there are 58 of them, the earliest ones are behind this "...". My question is, is it possible to get the full list of the commits in the feature branch?

**Note**: the branch is being deleted after it gets merged into master, so there is no way to do `git log feature_branch`

Comment: Was master merged into feature branch? Or was the feature branch created, 58 commits made on the branch, and the branch eventually merged?

Comment: Or are you asking about `git --no-pager log …`? (Use your cursor keys or the space bar to scroll in the pager)

Comment: the feature branch created, 58 commits made on the branch, and the branch eventually merged

Comment: If you're doing an *actual merge*, the commits from the feature branch are now in the target branch. If you're doing a *squash merge* there aren't any commits any more, so that's a problem (but squash merge isn't a merge, don't use it unless you're really sure you want that).

Comment: @torek good point about a squash-merge; the "(58 commits)" would fit. In that case the branch history is lost. One more reason not to use squash-merges.

Comment: As far as I understand, the commits have not been squashed. Otherwise I would not have got these 20 latest commits, right?

Comment: I'm guessing that you did a real merge, but the usual problem here is that people show us a bit of sample code that's not the actual code, so we have to guess what the real code was, when it was used, etc. That's why I tend to hedge a bit here. :-) To get the commits from the side branch, use the merge's second parent as a positive ref and the merge's first parent as a negative ref and drop all the --since/--until stuff (that's quite error-prone).

Comment: @GrigoryKrasovsky: the way your output is formatted, you could be looking at a squash merge where the commit message was built by putting together the commit messages. Run `git show 0db13700603e` to see if that particular commit has a long commit message, check your repository's settings to see if pull requests are "squashed and merged" when accepted.

Comment: what's the hosting service ? gihub ? gitlab ? azure devops ? ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this was a real merge (and not a squash-merge which only puts the old commit messages as *text* into the merge commit message):

```
git log ^mergecommit^1 mergecommit^2
```

- `^mergecommit^1` means `--not mergecommit^1`, i.e. exclude all commits reachable from the first parent of the merge commit (generally your main line of development)
- `mergecommit^2` includes all commits reachable from the second parent of the merge commit (usually your feature branch)